# What are some good flat pedal shoes for XC racing?

Tags: product-rec, pedals, shoes, shopping

Like the title says, I'm looking for some recommendations on good flat pedal shoes. This could include ones with an SPD or other interface that has removable clips. I'm currently riding with a set of 5.10 Freeriders, which offer great traction and grip to flats, but are really heavy.

At some point, I'll probably have to force myself to race clipped in, but for now I love my ability to quickly dab and destroy any downhill sections.

Quick breakdown of what I'm looking for:

- **Light weight**
- **Grippy/good traction**
- **No clips/removable clips**

Comment: I think everything is going to be in the Freeride/ AM/ Enduro category unless you change to clip ins. I don't have a problem getting out of the clips to dab, but have actually been concentrating on not doing it this season and have had quicker times.

Answer (score 4):

- [Five Ten Freerider VXi Elements](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/five-ten-freerider-vxi-shoes/rp-prod93891) - 398 gram
- [Five Ten Freerider](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/five-ten-freerider-mtb-shoes/rp-prod93011) - 399 gram
- [Giro Jacket](http://www.giro.com/us_en/jacket.html) - 416 gram
- [Shimano AM41](http://www.bikemag.com/gear/review-shimano-am41/) - 420 gram
- [Teva Links](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Teva-Links-Shoe-review-2011.html) - 440 gram
- [661 Filter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/2014-661-Mens-Filter-Black/dp/B00EZO5NJK) - 680 Gram

So basically, all the available (excluding high-top shoes) flat pedal shoes weigh the same. You could theoretically shave 1 gram by switching to the Freerider VXi Elements, but that would hardly be worth the money.

An alternative could be some light weight skate shoes, but then you would probably loose out on grip and the weight savings would probably still be negligible.

And for comparison [Diadora X-Trail 2 Carbon SPD shoes](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/no/en/diadora-x-trail-2-carbon-mtb-shoes-2013/rp-prod86650) are 335 gram.

Comment: The soles in skate shoes don't offer the stiffness most people like on flats.

Comment: @DWGKNZ You don't need a stiff sole when riding flatties. You are standing on the pedal, and it provides the support and doesn't bend. Five Ten aren't particularly stiff either, although perhaps slightly more than skate shoes. They do however have a pretty thick sole. The main problem with skate shoes are the grip, not the stiffness.

Comment: The Shimano is linked to the Teva page, could you please fix that?